# Search github repository (or subdirectory of repository) for a string without cloning?

Tags: github

Suppose we want to search [this](https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/trunk/src/library/tools/R) subdirectory for all occurrences of the string `startHTTPD`

Is there a way to do this without cloning first? (i.e. just using a browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be guaranteed up-to-date results, then you have to clone the repository.  GitHub will index repositories, but it doesn't necessarily do that frequently, and it doesn't let you search just in a subdirectory.

You can search a repository by entering text in the search bar in the top left of the window, and choosing “In this repository.”

In your particular case, the repository was last indexed in 2018, so it's likely a bit out of date.